# max size to still fit 20MB Appstore limitation?

Tags: iphone, app-store, xcodebuild

on some telecomunication services like AT&T or Telecom there is a 20MB download limitation for gprs/umts - so if an app is over 20mb you need WiFi to download the app.

Is there a known maxsize for the zipped app file to still fit this 20MB limitation ? 
After I zipped my .app file my finder say its 19,9MB (19.922.768 Bytes) - I heared somewhere that Apple is going to add some stuff like provision file and some other bytes I do not know. So would that app fit the 20MB limitation? How many bytes apple is going to add? Is apple counting 1000 or 1024 bytes for a kilo?

Answer (score 0):

I havent heard of "app store limits".

Theres an AT&T artificially imposed 20mb D/L limit in the US.

Otherwise people can DL any size apps with wifi